# How to add stroke to rectangle based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add black stroke to rectangle based on data. For example, I just want to add stroke to rectangle that represent salary over 4000, I used the normal d3.js code to add the stroke but turn out add stroke to all the rectangle. How can I just add stroke to a certain group of data?

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .style("fill",function(d){ 
        return d.salary  >= 4000 ? d3.color("green") : 'yellow';
    })
    .style('fill-opacity',0.5)
    .style("stroke", 'black') 
    .style("stroke-width",0.2);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the same ternary you used to the fill? `.style("stroke",function(d){ return d.salary  >= 4000 ? "black" : "none"; })`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, it works! Thanks!